# Way to append strings to the start of another String?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

Im trying to create a scoreboard and append or add another box to the existing box.

```
String res = "";
    res += "+-----+\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        res += "|     |\n";
    }
    res += "+-----+";
```

Prints out +-----+ at top and bottom, with |    | on the sides.
Im trying to add -----+ to the top, dependent on how many of a variable is input. And then add the | | sides in total to make:

```
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

2 boxes. The second one is attached to the first one.
The program is being done in a method, so I can only return 1 string.  I would like to just use the existing box, and concat the -----+ to the top and | | to the sides, but the original box program ends at the bottom. Is there a way to start it back to the top, so I could add the other strings to the existing box?

My current code for adding another box is the recreate the first box, and try to add the extra stuff but its not working because it puts the additions on the bottom, and the first | | is always attached instead of adjacent.

```
+-----+-----+|     |
|     |
|     |
|     |
+-----+|     |
|     |
|     |
|     |
+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

To append<sup>1</sup> a string at the start of a string:

```
String str = "Hello";
str = "at start " + str;
System.out.println(str);  // outputs "at start Hello"
```

There isn't a specific shortcut operator (like `+=`) to do this.  But you don't need an operator.

Having said that, if you are concatenating strings in a loop it is often *significantly* more efficient to use a `StringBuilder` explicitly.

---

<sup>1 - The correct term for this is "prepend".  The word "append" means add at the end.  "Append at the start" is a contradiction.</sup>